# How can i Stop UITableview cell reloaded While Scrolling the UITableview in iPhone..?

Tags: iphone, ios6, uitableview, uiswitch

I have already tried to implement UISwitch in the tabeleview cell,now the switch state is automatically changed while i scroll and change the view ,

Please guide me....

Comment: please provide some code to answer your question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `NSMutableDictionary` for holding the information regarding particular cell `UISwitch` object. If you have enable a UISwitch button for a cell then set Bool yes and tag value as well in the `NSMutableDictionary`.
Enable the switch for a particular cell object according to `NSMutableDictionary` values in cellFor rowAtIndexPath.

Answer (score 0):

UITableview  reuses the cells, to solve your problem you need to create NSArray for switch states and assign as user scroll up and down (Using NSIndexPath).